# Existing nodes freeze upon new data entering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Upon binding new link and node data to the force layout and svg elements, the old nodes and links freeze. The new nodes and links of the `enter()` selection also do not connect to the existing nodes.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8rgyh2L/2/)

*Why* is this issue occurring?

I have browsed the various similar questions, but none give a satisfactory *why* answer. Please note that I have also thoroughly read the often cited "thinking with joins", enter/update/exit selection articles. Something's not clicking here, though.

```
start(graph);

  force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });

  window.setTimeout(function(){
        graph.nodes.push({"name":"Westby","group":2})
        graph.links.push({"source":5,"target":2,"value":1})
      start(graph);
  }, 2000);


function start(graph){
    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .call(force.drag)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Code revisions*

You need to run `force.start()` *after* you modify the layout.  All of the configuration of the layout is done in `force.start()`.

`nodes` and `links` don't need to be re-bound each time you change the data.

I also changed the structure to a pattern that gives you maximum control and flexibility.
With this pattern you can manage the update, enter and exit components separately.

One final tweek was to use

```
link.enter().insert("line", "circle.node")
```

instead of

```
link.enter().append("line")
```

This is to make sure that the link renders behind the circle.

### *Revised code*

```
force
  //you only need to do this once///////////
  .nodes(graph.nodes)  
  .links(graph.links)
  //////////////////////////////////////////
  .on("tick", function () {
  link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
  });

start(graph);

window.setTimeout(function () {
  graph.nodes.push({ "name": "Westby", "group": 2 })
  graph.links.push({ "source": 5, "target": 2, "value": 1 })
  start(graph);
}, 2000);

function start(graph) {
  //UPDATE  pre-existing nodes to be re-cycled
  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links);
  //ENTER new nodes to be created
  link.enter().insert("line", "circle.node")  //insert before node!
      .attr("class", "link")
  //UPDATE+ENTER  .enter also merges update and enter, link is now both
  link.style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
  //EXIT
  link.exit().remove()
  //UPDATE
  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
  //ENTER
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .call(force.drag);
  //UPDATE+ENTER  .enter also merges update and enter, link is now both
  node.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
  //EXIT
  node.exit().remove();

  node.append("title")
      .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

  force.start();
}
```

## *Background*

### *Data binding*

`d3.layout.force` maintains closures on *references* to the `nodes` and `links` arrays, so you only need to bind the layout to the array references once.
As you can see when you read the code...

```
d3.layout.force = function () {
  var force = {},
      //...
      nodes = [], links = [], distances, strengths, charges;
  //...
  force.nodes = function (x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
    nodes = x;
    return force;
  };
  force.links = function (x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return links;
    links = x;
    return force;
  };
  //...
};
```

So we have

```
force().nodes(nodesData);
force().links(linksData);

force().nodes() === nodesData  // true
force().links() === linksData  // true
```

Further more, because of the way data binding works in d3, each of the DOM nodes in the selection structure has a reference to one element of it's respective data array.  This is stored on the `__data__` member that d3 adds to the DOM nodes.

*Since the array elements are generally complex objects*,

```
__data__ === nodesData[i] // true
```

for the i'th member of the selection with data bound to it.

The `selection.datum()` method returns the value of the `__data__` member of the selected node (or the first non-null node in the selection), the value being the reference to the data array element.  This means of course that any modification to the members of a data array element are automatically reflected in the data binding of the selection and anything that references the `__data__` member of the nodes.

It's worth noting at this point however, that the object returned by

```
update = selection.data(values)
```

is a *new* array so we have

```
update.data() === values  // false
update.data()[i] === values[i]  // true
```

### *Roles and references (summary)*

The node and link ***data*** are stored as arrays of objects.  The members of the array *elements* are the information required to inform the visualisation - *types* of nodes or links, labels for them, grouping information etc..

The ***force layout*** is *bound* to the *data* by *referencing* the data arrays:

```
force().nodes(nodesData);
force().links(linksData);

force().nodes() === nodesData  // true
force().links() === linksData  // true
```

The ***selections*** are bound to the data by *referencing* the data array *elements*:

```
nodes = selection.data(nodesData); links.enter().append(nodeSelector)
links = selection.data(linksData); links.enter().append(linkSelector)

nodes === nodesData  //false - nodes is a selection, nodesData is an array
nodes.data() === nodesData  //false - nodes.data() returns a new array
nodes.data()[i] === nodesData[i]  //true! - the elements of the data array are coppied to the new array that is returned by the selection

//similar for links
```

The force layout and the selections reference the same data (in different ways!) but ***do not reference each other***.

The ***role*** of the force layout is to ***manage animation events*** (frames) by using it's internal dynamics settings to *calculate node positions* every `tick`.  Whenever a ***data structure event*** occurs, the force layout needs to be informed by a call to `force.start()` (if you want to know why, get the d3 source and RTFC).

The ***role*** of the selections is to ***manage DOM elements*** by binding data to them and providing an API for *managing them in terms of the data*.  Whenever a ***data structure event*** occurs, the selections need to be informed by an update/enter/append cycle.

In the tick event provided by the force layout API, the selections are used to drive the visualisation (DOM elements) in terms of the new data calculated by the force layout.

### *Dynamically changing force layout structure*

If you use the browser developer tools to look at the elements of the array returned by force.nodes(), you will see that there is a lot of state added over and above the original members, there is also state closured in the d3.force object such as distances, strengths and charges. All this has to be set up somewhere and not surprisingly, it's done in `force.start()`. So that's why you have to call `force.start()` every time you change the structure of the data.

### *General Pattern*

Generally speaking, this is the most defensive pattern...

```
//UPDATE
var update = baseSelection.selectAll(elementSelector)
            .data(values, key),
    //ENTER
        enter = update.enter().append(appendElement)
            .call(initStuff),
    //enter() has side effect of adding enter nodes to the update selection
    //so anything you do to update now will include the enter nodes

    //UPDATE+ENTER
        updateEnter = update
            .call(stuffToDoEveryTimeTheDataChanges);
    //EXIT
    exit = update.exit().remove()
```

First time through `update` will be an array of nulls with the same structure as the data.
The `.selectAll()` returns a zero length selection in this case and does nothing useful.

On subsequent updates, `.selectAll` will not be empty and will be compared to `values`, using `keys`, to determine which nodes are update, enter and exit nodes.  That's why you need the select before the data join.

The important thing to understand is that it has to be `.enter().append(...)`, so you are appending elements on the enter selection.  If you append them on the update selection (the one returned by the data join) then you will re-enter the same elements and see similar behaviour to what you are getting.

The enter selection is an array of simple objects of the form `{ __data__: data }`
The update and exit selections are arrays of arrays of references to DOM elements.

The data method in d3 keeps a closure on the enter and exit selections which are accessed by `.enter()` and `.exit()` methods on `update`.    Both return objects which, among other things, are 2-D arrays (All selections in d3 are arrays of groups, where groups are arrays of nodes.). 
the `enter` member is also given a reference to `update` so that it can merge the two.  This is done because, in the majority of cases, the same stuff is done to both groups.

Comment: This is weird. It seems that defining `exit()` behavior was the key here. After binding `graph.nodes` and `graph.links` to the force layout once -- you were right about needing to so so only once -- the proper behavior seems to depend on whether `exit()` is defined. Why is this? If force layout maintains a reference to graph.links and graph.nodes, there should not be any elements in the `exit()` selection when I am only adding nodes and links.

Comment: Nevermind, I lied. It doesn't seem to be dependent on `exit()`

Comment: @Gnuey, yes, bad wording from me sent you off on a tangent, I mentioned exit because You were talking about enter/update/exit but the root cause of your problem was the position of the `force.start()` statement. I included the explanation about data binding because of a comment I saw in your code which made me suspect that you had the wrong idea about this.

Comment: Yep! Turns out I was completely wrong. Thank you for clarifying that and countering that statement! I also think that another key problem with my code was the fact that I chained `.enter()` immediately after `.data()` and that caused the `link` and `node` variables to only acquire the enter selection. This meant that the `.on("tick", function () {
  link.attr(....
  node.attr(...
  });` behavior only applied to the *enter* selection. But, as you mention, the solution is to call `.enter()` separately after `.data()`, so that `link` and `node` selections reference both enter and update. Correct?

Comment: (`link` and `node` are *references* to the update/enter selections, right?)

Comment: @Gnuey, often it's fine to do everything on the enter selection but often not... take a look at the variable names in my example: `initStuff` and `stuffToDoEveryTimeTheDataChanges`. If the existing nodes don't need to be "refreshed" as a result of data events, then no need to do anything with the update selection.  I recommend that pattern because, if you use it, you will naturally think like that and you will systematically think in terms of the specific needs for update, enter, update+enter and exit.

Comment: @Gnuey, `link` and `node` are ***d3 selection objects***. They are arrays of sparse arrays of DOM elements and `__data__` objects.  The "gaps" in the sparse arrays are the nodes missing from the selection.  After `.data()` and `.enter()`, `link` and `node` are arrays of arrays of DOM elements with the DOM elements each having `__data__` properties added to them.  The value of each of the `__data__` members is a _reference_ to one of the _elements_ of the data arrays (provided they are arrays of complex objects).

Comment: After adding the new node and link (for Westby) to `graph.nodes` and `graph.links`, I tried printing out `node` between `.data()` and `.enter()` calls, and both return an array containing *all* 6 node elements (including the node / links for Westby). Why is this? Shouldn't the first print of `node` only return 5 node elements? I.e. I did this:
`node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)......
  console.log("node before enter():");
  console.log(node);    // returns len 6 arr???
  nodeEnter = node.enter()....
  console.log("node after enter():");
  console.log(node + nodeEnter);`

Comment: Thanks so much for your excellent and thorough response by the way! Probably one of the best answers I've seen on SO.

Comment: @Gnuey, use your browser tools to put a break point on the console.log statement and check the actual elements of the array. The six'th element will be null, or you won't even see it in the array. The _length_ of the array is set to the _greater_ of the number of nodes or the updated data array length, but the extra nodes are not materialised until `.enter()` is called. This is why d3 has a `selection.size()` method, `node.size()` will return 5 at that point.